# How to find the list that contains the higher value from nested list and return those lists?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have this nested list which contains duplicate entries:

```
[['Coloring book moana', 'ART_AND_DESIGN', '3.9', 967, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up'],
 ['Coloring book moana', 'FAMILY', '3.9', 974, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up'],
 ['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604324, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604483, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577313, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577446, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66509917, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']]
```

I want to filter the nested list by i[3] so the final output will be like this

```
[['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604483, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Coloring book moana', 'FAMILY', '3.9', 974, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up'],
 ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577446, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']]
```

I tried a for loop but I can't figure out how to get the highest value of duplicate lists

Comment: I would suggest using a different data structure. Have you used pandas before? This is a natural usage for a DataFrame.

Comment: What does "filter by i[3]" mean? is this a new buzzword I'm not quite onto yet? Do you simply want the unique values? Have you looked at [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)?

Comment: @PMende the task is to do it using only python not pandas

Comment: @Chase i[3] refers to the index of each sublist which is the number of reviews on each application. I want to select the list that has the highest number of reviews and drop the other (which is a duplicate list for the same app and the only difference is in the number of reviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the most pythonic way I could come up with. My approach is to sort the list of lists first, by `sublist[3]`, which means when we traverse the list, we'll end up encountering the sublist with the maximum review numbers before we encounter its duplicate. This trick will be used to construct the final list.

```py
meta_list = [['Coloring book moana', 'ART_AND_DESIGN', '3.9', 967, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up'],
 ['Coloring book moana', 'FAMILY', '3.9', 974, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up'],
 ['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604324, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604483, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577313, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577446, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
 ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66509917, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']]

# Sort the list by review count and review name - make sure the highest review is first
meta_list.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x[3]), x[0]), reverse=True)

# This is the list we'll use to store the final data in
final_list = []
# Go through all the items in the meta_list
for meta in meta_list:
    
    if not meta[0] in [item[0] for item in final_list]:
        '''
        If another meta with the same name (0th index)
        doesn't already exist in final_list, add it
        '''
        final_list.append(meta)
```

Output-

```
[['Instagram',
  'SOCIAL',
  '4.5',
  66577446,
  'Varies with device',
  '1,000,000,000+',
  'Free',
  '0',
  'Teen',
  'Social',
  'July 31, 2018',
  'Varies with device',
  'Varies with device'],
 ['Gmail',
  'COMMUNICATION',
  '4.3',
  4604483,
  'Varies with device',
  '1,000,000,000+',
  'Free',
  '0',
  'Everyone',
  'Communication',
  'August 2, 2018',
  'Varies with device',
  'Varies with device'],
 ['Coloring book moana',
  'FAMILY',
  '3.9',
  974,
  '14M',
  '500,000+',
  'Free',
  '0',
  'Everyone',
  'Art & Design;Pretend Play',
  'January 15, 2018',
  '2.0.0',
  '4.0.3 and up']]
```

Basically it adds all the metas that don't already exist to the `final_list`. Why does this work? Because the **first meta** you encounter while looping is the one **with the highest review count**. So as soon as that one gets added, its dupes can't get added and we're done.

**Note**: This won't preserve the order of the reviews themselves. It'll only make sure that only the reviews with the highest review count is preserved, in case there are dupes with the same name.

Comment: Wow!! @Chase I really liked your way. It's more simple than other solutions. Thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a more elegant / pythonic solution to this problem, but here's one possible route:

```py
my_list = [...] # Nested list here

def compare_duplicates(nested_list, name_index=0, compare_index=3):
    max_values = dict() # Used two dictionaries for readability
    final_indexes = dict()

    for i, item in enumerate(nested_list):
        name, value = item[name_index], item[compare_index]

        if value > max_values.get(name, 0):
            max_values[name] = value
            final_indexes[name] = i

    return [nested_list[i] for i in final_indexes.values()]

print(compare_duplicates(my_list))
```

Comment: ```TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()``` I got this error

Comment: Are you sure the third index (i[3] in your example) is an integer, and not a string like the other values? Try changing `if value > max_values.get(name, 0):` to `if int(value) > max_values.get(name, 0):` Keep in mind that this is a very inelegant solution, and prone to bugs.

Comment: Just to re-emphasize PMende's recommendation to use Pandas for this situation: It's well-optimized for data type-handling and this "max value in redundant rows" case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
_DATA = [
    ['Coloring book moana', 'ART_AND_DESIGN', '3.9', 967, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up'],
    ['Coloring book moana', 'ART_AND_DESIGN', '3.9', 974, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up'],
    ['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604324, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
    ['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604483, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
    ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577313, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
    ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577446, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device'],
    ['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66509917, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']
]


def print_highest(data):
    list_map = {}
    for d in data:
        key = str(d[0:3] + d[4:])
        if key not in list_map:
            list_map[key] = d
            continue

        if d[3] > list_map[key][3]:
            list_map[key] = d

    for l in list_map.values():
        print(l)


print_highest(_DATA)
```

Output:

```
['Coloring book moana', 'ART_AND_DESIGN', '3.9', 974, '14M', '500,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Art & Design;Pretend Play', 'January 15, 2018', '2.0.0', '4.0.3 and up']
['Gmail', 'COMMUNICATION', '4.3', 4604483, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Everyone', 'Communication', 'August 2, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']
['Instagram', 'SOCIAL', '4.5', 66577446, 'Varies with device', '1,000,000,000+', 'Free', '0', 'Teen', 'Social', 'July 31, 2018', 'Varies with device', 'Varies with device']
```

Comment: Why are you adding `_` underscores before pretty much every variable? Is there a particular reason to do this?

Comment: Your function doesn't actually use the parameter `data` anywhere.

Comment: @PMende Corrected. _DATA is defined here just to run the program without standard input. Later the user can just put this function anywhere they want and plug in the data.